# $A_n$ is simple if $n \ge 5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

I have been working on this proof for some time taking reference form Lang. I understand that if we prove that if every normal subgroup of $A_n$ contains some 3-cycles then the proof is complete.

Now I can prove till the fact that if $\sigma \in N$ where N is a non-trivial subgroup of $A_n$, and $\sigma$ is the element such that it has the maximal number of elements left unmoved, then it can't be a product of two independent 2-cycles. I can also prove the part part (b) of Lang's proof as given below:

[image]

Now my question is, why would you stop there? I mean why would you only assume that $\sigma$ moves five elements and prove that it then can't be the element in N such that it has the maximal number of unmoved points? Why can't you assume that $\sigma$ moves 6 points or more? If someone could help me out with the last part of the proof, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: why are you calling the element $n$ instead of $\sigma$ ? it makes it a bit confusing since $n$ is already the index of the alternating group.

Comment: Please don’t rely on images; they cannot be searched, they dsiplay statically so they don’t interact well with every interface, and screen readers cannot scan them, making your post inaccessible to those who use them. The site has very good mathematical typesetting with MathJax, so please use that.

Comment: Lang is saying that $\sigma$ moves **at least** five elements. Not exactly five.